# Trying to reverse web application connection, but the network tab shows nothing

Tags: networking

I've been checking out metaverse-sensation Decentraland (play.decentraland.org) and I'm interested in how they've implemented the massive multiplayer netcode to work well for tens of players at the same screen. So I decided to monitor the network.

I logged in with 2 browsers, got both on the same game screen looking at each other, and monitored the network tab on my browser to see what was being sent. To my surprise, when I move the character on one window, the other one sees the movement, but no data is sent over Chrome's network tab.

I'm surely missing something. How can I see what data it's sending and where it's sending to? Are there some types of connections on browser that do not trigger the network tab? How can I debug them?

Comment: The network tab sees only HTTP(S) and may be WebSocket connections (see also [this question on WebSocket traffic](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37413092/150978)).

Comment: I suggest using Fiddler or Wireshark

Answer (score 1):

You can use Wireshark tool which is available here: https://www.wireshark.org
Repeat all your steps while you're sniffing network connections, see if it solves the problem

Answer (score 1):

The web application may use the browser's raw socket API or something similar  for TCP and/or UDP protocol (extensions, java stuff, etc.)

The browser's HTTP(s) debugger - actually any HTTP(s) debugger - won't and can't display such connections and traffic which are not HTTP compliant.

As the other answer: You'd need an entire network sniffer such as Wireshark